# What does it mean when a feature or variable has non-significant t test statistics but significant p values in F test (anova)?

Tags: r, regression

I ran a linear regression model with 15 features in R. 5 of them are categorical features (converted to factors and first category dropped for each of them). 10 are continuous features (already scaled).

When i ran the `summary` function, the t-test statistic for `continuous_H` is not significant. However, when I ran `anova` function, the p-value for the same variable is significant. (highlighted below)

Can someone explain why this issue is happening? And how can I detect and avoid this problem before fitting model ?

```
> model1 <- lm(y~., data=dff)
> summary(model1)

Call:
lm(formula = y~ ., data = dff)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-0.43882 -0.04287 -0.01424  0.02811  0.55683 

Coefficients:
                            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                -0.087020   0.036753  -2.368  0.01795 *  
continuous_A                0.014989   0.001999   7.499 7.90e-14 ***
continuous_B                0.914243   0.001551 589.386  < 2e-16 ***
continuous_C                0.009622   0.001257   7.655 2.41e-14 ***
continuous_D                0.040113   0.001246  32.201  < 2e-16 ***
continuous_E                -0.018539   0.001395 -13.286  < 2e-16 ***
continuous_F                0.041024   0.001893  21.676  < 2e-16 ***
continuous_G                0.018972   0.001424  13.327  < 2e-16 ***
continuous_H                -0.001611   0.001287  -1.252  0.21079 <--- Issue: non significant here
continuous_I                0.003163   0.001308   2.418  0.01565 *  
continuous_J                1.227182   0.001559 787.057  < 2e-16 ***
discrete_A_Cat2            -0.011020   0.005658  -1.948  0.05152 .  
discrete_A_Cat3            -0.010511   0.004659  -2.256  0.02411 *  
discrete_A_Cat4            -0.033604   0.007954  -4.225 2.44e-05 ***
discrete_A_Cat5            -0.009018   0.004937  -1.827  0.06784 .  
discrete_A_Cat6            -0.016998   0.012186  -1.395  0.16314    
discrete_A_Cat7            -0.015049   0.005187  -2.901  0.00374 ** 
discrete_A_Cat8            -0.007899   0.005317  -1.486  0.13748    
discrete_A_Cat9            -0.009546   0.004872  -1.959  0.05016 .  
discrete_A_Cat10            0.006813   0.006124   1.113  0.26596    
discrete_B_Cat2             0.017450   0.003159   5.524 3.52e-08 ***
discrete_C_Cat2             0.064552   0.035405   1.823  0.06834 .  
discrete_C_Cat3             0.011940   0.035305   0.338  0.73524    
discrete_D_Cat2             0.065295   0.009673   6.750 1.69e-11 ***
discrete_D_Cat3             0.072199   0.016010   4.510 6.68e-06 ***
discrete_D_Cat4             0.047830   0.009637   4.963 7.23e-07 ***
discrete_D_Cat5             0.059050   0.010224   5.775 8.26e-09 ***
discrete_D_Cat6            -0.004001   0.011561  -0.346  0.72928    
discrete_D_Cat7             0.131548   0.021267   6.185 6.82e-10 ***
discrete_D_Cat8             0.071839   0.010517   6.831 9.72e-12 ***
discrete_E_Cat2             0.051081   0.008739   5.845 5.48e-09 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.07769 on 3975 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.994, Adjusted R-squared:  0.994 
F-statistic: 2.198e+04 on 30 and 3975 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16

> anova(model1)
Analysis of Variance Table

Response: y
                       Df Sum Sq Mean Sq    F value    Pr(>F)    
continuous_A            1    3.0     3.0 5.0505e+02 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_B            1  130.4   130.4 2.1609e+04 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_C            1   16.7    16.7 2.7597e+03 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_D            1   30.1    30.1 4.9899e+03 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_E            1    1.0     1.0 1.6198e+02 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_F            1   14.4    14.4 2.3844e+03 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_G            1    0.1     0.1 1.2657e+01 0.0003785 ***
continuous_H            1    0.5     0.5 7.5951e+01 < 2.2e-16 *** <- Issue: significant here
continuous_I            1   14.8    14.8 2.4466e+03 < 2.2e-16 ***
continuous_J            1 3766.6  3766.6 6.2400e+05 < 2.2e-16 ***
discrete_A              9    0.4     0.0 6.9891e+00 4.480e-10 ***
discrete_B              1    0.4     0.4 6.4573e+01 1.215e-15 ***
discrete_C              2    1.4     0.7 1.1742e+02 < 2.2e-16 ***
discrete_D              7    1.0     0.1 2.4816e+01 < 2.2e-16 ***
discrete_E              1    0.2     0.2 3.4163e+01 5.475e-09 ***
Residuals            3975   24.0     0.0                         
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘

**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```